# Flash Storage Settings

Tags: 14.04, flash

I know this has been asked before, but how do I change the Adobe Flash Player storage settings in Ubuntu 14.04? I DO know that the following link: https://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html

[image]
<sup>**⠀Website Storage Settings panel**</sup>

can be used, but when I access it, it shows me nothing in "list of websites". Is there any other way to change the Flash storage settings? Also, right clicking on Flash content, then on Settings, does not work.